# Autofac - ForAllOtherMembers - Mapper not used

Tags: automapper

I have implemented the CaseInsensitiveFromStringDictionaryMapper as proposed here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3243
I also have registered this mapper into autofac with the following code

```
protected void ConfigureAutomapper(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var assembly in GetAssemblies(CustomAssembliesPrefix))
        {
            cfg.AddMaps(assembly);
        }

        cfg.Mappers.Insert(0, new CaseInsensitiveFromStringDictionaryMapper());
    });

    try
    {
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
    catch (AutoMapperConfigurationException ex)
    {
        var message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendLine("Automapper configuration error");

        Exception exception = ex;
        while (exception != null)
        {
            message.AppendLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
            message.AppendLine($"Stack trace: ");
            message.AppendLine($"{ex.StackTrace}");
            message.AppendLine($"");
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }

        EventLogProvider.LogEvent(EventType.ERROR, nameof(WebContainer), "Automapper configuration error", message.ToString());
        throw;
    }
    builder.Register(c => new Mapper(config))
        .As<IMapper>()
        .SingleInstance();
}
```

if I just do that, I am able to execute the following code and it maps all the properties of my target object perfectly:
`mapper.Map<ReferenceSearchResultDocument>(documentSearchResult.Document)`

But I need to some specific stuffs on some members so I have created a Profile and a mapping for those members but I would like to have the default behavior (so watching case insensitively in my dictionary) for my other members.
I have tested the following code:
`.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name]))` 
but of course it isn't the same as letting the mappers doing they jobs.

How could I fix it?

Regards,

Benjamin

Comment: You should write your own mapper that does what you want. You can start from the existing one.

Comment: The mappers collection is a chain of responsability. So if a mapper returns false from `IsMatch` the mapping will be handled by the rest of the mappers. But you need to decide that just based on the source and destination types.

Comment: Ok thank you for your helps I finally succeeded to achieved what I wanted by playing with the IsMatch method! Thanks a lot!